# Basic typedef/alias of a static variable

Tags: c++

How can I typedef/alias this into something more basic like ProjectInstance:

```
((ProjectType*)NamespaceOne::NamespaceTwo::ClassName::StaticVariable)->x=0;
```

This is a static class and calling it by namespace+casting it every time is annoying.

How can I simplify this into an alias of some sort so I can just refer to it as

```
ProjectInstance->x=0;
```

I was originally thinking something along these lines:

```
#typedef ((ProjectType*)NamespaceOne::NamespaceTwo::ClassName::StaticVariable) ProjectInstance
```

Where ProjectInstance is the alias for StaticVariable casted into ProjecType*.

```
NamespaceOne::NamespaceTwo::ClassName::StaticVariable
```

StaticVariable is an instance of BaseType. ProjectType extends BaseType, I am simply casting StaticVariable to ProjectType because there is an additional variable "x" in ProjectType class.

What I am trying to avoid:
Declaring a pointer/function in each class where I need to access this static variable.

So far the solution is "using namespace", while I was aware of this before, it's the best posted solution so far.

So we cut our original line of code into:

```
 ((ProjectType*)ClassName::StaticVariable)->x=0;
```

I have another solution:

```
 ClassName::ProjectStaticVariable->x=0;
```

By creating a new pointer inside the "ClassName" class I was able to cut it down even more.

Are there any better ways to cut this down even further?

Comment: What is a "static class"?

Comment: Doh, I renamed my variable to StaticClass by mistake, I meant to say StaticVariable.

Comment: Why are you casting? Why isn't the `StaticVariable` of type `ProjectType*` already?

Comment: Because StaticVariable is an instance of another class and ProjectType is extending that base class.

Comment: Uhm, and is `x` defined in base or derived class? This is asking for trouble.

Comment: @jrok Why would it matter where x is defined? The example code is perfectly valid, except of course the names of my namespaces and variables.

Comment: @Grapes It does matter. [Weird things may happen.](http://ideone.com/DVIL12) Your code may be syntacticaly valid, but that doesn't neccesarily mean it's not invoking undefined behaviour somewhere.

Comment: @jrok Sorry for not explaning myself correctly the first time. I am not casting into a base class but into a derived class. StaticVariable is an instance of BaseClass not the other way around.

Comment: I got it the first time you explained. You're doing shady things :) Why don't you create a minimal compilable example and show exactly how you declare and initilize your data?

Comment: @jrok A lesson learned, I'll be sure to include better examples next time. I did end up with a good solution, I posted it at the end of my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call `using directive` locally?

```
using namespace NamespaceOne::NamespaceTwo::NamespaceThree;
// do something to StaticVariable
```

Comment: Did mistaken something? please explain downvote :)

Comment: -1. You're typedefing a variable.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted you, but can you really "typedef" variables?

Comment: How about call `using directive` locally?

Comment: @Nawaz Please can you remove the downvote? I've updated my answer

Comment: @billz Thanks, that'll make it much cleaner. I'll still have to cast, but that's ok.

Comment: What is `ProjectInstance`?

Comment: @Nawaz yeah, looks like could access `StaticVariable->x` directly

Comment: @Nawaz why is static_cast still important in this case?

Comment: But in the question, there is a cast, which implies (by its usage) `staticVariable` and `ProjectInstance` are different types.

Comment: Haha. Now with this static_cast and using namespace statement, it is not that cleaner. And moreover, using namespace statement pollutes the  current namespace.

Comment: @Nawaz I posted my explanation in the question Nawaz.

Comment: @Nawaz There is no necessary of statc_cast at all!

Comment: @billz: But the OP is using it. How can say that is not necessary untill he says they're both type?

Comment: @Grapes: Your question is confusing. You're assuming too much about your knowledge of C++, which is why you've made so many wrong conclusions in the question.

Comment: @Nawaz not sure what you mean by wrong conclusions, but I would like to clear up the question as much as I can.

Comment: @Grapes: You said *"What I am trying to avoid: Declaring a pointer/function in each class where I need to access this static variable."*  .. WHY? What if I suggest a non-member function (like I did my answer).  From your comments on my answer, it seems that you think adding member function to a class increases the size of the class. No, it doesn't!

Answer (score 1):

You can use some function as:

```
ProjectType* ProjectInstance()
{
  return static_cast<ProjectType*>(NamespaceOne::NamespaceTwo::NamespaceThree::StaticVariable);
}
```

And use it as:

```
ProjectInstance()->x = 0;
```

Comment: I am trying to do something during compilation time. Otherwise I could just declare a ProjectInstance variable inside that class as a pointer to NamespaceOne::NamespaceTwo::NamespaceThree::StaticVariable.

Comment: @Grapes: You're doing `ProjectInstance->x = 0;` at compile time? How exactly?

Comment: I am just looking for a solution that would not actually add any overhead. Wouldn't your approach add extra information to the class and increase it's size?

Comment: @Grapes: You're not providing any information as to what you're actually doing, how is it possible to give you any solution? I answered the question which is posted, not the question which is in your mind.

Comment: The function will be inlined... Whoo, no overhead.

Comment: What size are you talking about? How would it increase the size of a class?

Comment: @Nawaz I further explained what I was trying to approach in the original question.